# How to serve Django and ASP.NET on same host in IIS?

Tags: c#, python, asp.net, django, iis

I have a web application built in ASP.Net and deployed on IIS 8. I need to integrate a django project with this application. Is it possible to do it? And if yes, how?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow!! It would be great if you could [read these guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking a new question. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This question is very broad. At first, you should at least define thoroughly what's the meaning of "integrate" in your case. Regarding the hosting of Django in IIS, you have to do something like this https://www.toptal.com/django/installing-django-on-iis-a-step-by-step-tutorial.

Comment: Hi, we have a web app created in asp.net. Now, I want to add some functionality to the web app. Is it possible to create this functionality in Django and host it on the same website?